# Finding embedded document by unique property in Mongoose ODM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have this Schemes:

```
var SubsetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    name: String,
});

var RootSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    subsets: [SubsetSchema],
});

mongoose.model('collection', RootSchema);
var Root = module.exports = mongoose.model('collection');
```

How would i perform search for a single `Subset` document across the whole collection where `number = 3`?

And i am not clear. In the case of schema above, would `number` be unique in the entire collection or per `Root` document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in the query and the [`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_) in the projection to filter the output to just the matched `subsets` element like this:

```
Root.findOne({'subsets.number': 3}, {_id: 0, 'subsets.$': 1}, ...);
```

Regarding your second question, `number` would be enforced as unique across the entire collection, but (counter-intuitively) would still be allowed to exist multiple times in the *same* `Root` document.

Comment: Great! Now i wonder if there is a way to get the clean object? Because now it returns me `{ "subsets" : [{...}] }` and i would love to get only `{...}` part. Of course i can do it within callback, but just for educational purpose wonder if this is possible. Regarding second question: could you explain a bit more? So if i have a unique parameter `number` in `Subsets`. Then within one `Root` document i can have two with same `number`?

Comment: @AlexKey No, I don't see how you can remove the `subsets` level of the doc directly in a `findOne`.  Regarding the unique index, yes, it makes sure you don't have two `Root` docs with the same `number` in `Subsets`, but doesn't prevent a single `Root` doc from having the same `number` more than once.